# Compound Poisson process for demand

Tags: prediction, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, compound-distributions

I have a demand pattern for a service part. Demand event rate of this part is Poisson distributed. Demand of the part is 3 times in a year. So the demand event rate is 0.25/Month. Each demand transaction has different demand quantities. These demand quantities has certain distribution  with mean of 100 and standard deviation of 120. Lead time of of the service part is 1 month. I want to identify what will be the demand quantity during its lead time of 1 month for probability of 95%. I want to use compound Poisson to address this problem

Comment: You wrote the background to your question, but I believe that you forgot to state the question itself.